# How can I set up communication between an android app and a python program?

Tags: python, java, android, sockets, p2p

I currently have a python application running on a raspberry pi, that has a tablet connected running an android application. Neither of them have an internet connection, and I was wondering if I can use sockets to allow both of them to communicate (P2P) and how to go about it. Im currently trying to have the java program send out two message then wait for a variable number of responses from the python program.

I haven't found any useful guides online about how to set up communication using the tablet as a USB accessory. This is a very small project, the messages being transferred would be just a line or two of text so if there are any other alternatives that would be easier would also be greatly beneficial.

Comment: When you connect without internet it's called a LAN. https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/feature/Whats-the-difference-between-internet-and-Ethernet

Comment: Alternately, for a homebrew (and also still some industrial projects) serial communication might be an option.    https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2019/12/06/what-is-rs485-and-its-difference-between-rs232/ (And for even more homebrew, I've also seen people connect op-amps directly to digital output to make their own serial bus. All depends on your requirements.)